# What picture is the $S$-matrix defined in?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, definition, s-matrix-theory

I am looking into the definition of the [$S$-matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix), and have found two different cases. Firstly I have seen it derived that (see [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yykTDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&dq=The%20S-matrix%20schrodinger%20picture&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI_-Pl3ZXPAhVFJcAKHYPCCtoQ6AEITTAH#v=snippet&q=heisenberg%20operator&f=false), link to Google books p110):
$$ S=U_S(\infty,-\infty)$$
But more commonly that (see [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nIk6AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Quantum%20Field%20Theory%20for%20the%20Gifted%20Amateur&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj43_idlZbPAhVDLMAKHbLnDGQQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=S-matrix&f=false), link to Google books p169):
$$S=U_I(\infty,-\infty)$$
(Where subscript $S$ represents the Schrödinger picture and $I$ the interaction). Are these two definitions identical? If so can this be shown and if not why two different definitions? Either way the latter seems to be preferred, why?

### Further Information/My guess:

This may come down to how we define $S$ from what I can tell it is define such that if your particle is in the Schrödinger state $|\psi_S(t)\rangle$ and you want to find the amplitude that at $t=\infty$ it is in the state $|\phi_S(t)\rangle$ then $S$ is defined such that:
$$\langle\psi_S(\infty)|S|\psi_S(-\infty)\rangle=\langle\psi_S(\infty)|\psi_S(\infty)\rangle$$
which would indicate my former rather then my latter definition. Thus different authors may be defining it in different ways?

Comment: Well, the *S*-matrix corresponds to matrix elements, and you are free to use any picture to compute those, expecting, of course, to find the *same* answer; so, typically, the Schroedinger, Heisenberg, or even interaction picture. There are advantages and disadvantages to each, but the WP article details them all.